# CSS Animation - Position To Original

Tags: jquery, css, animation, styles

Here's a simple script, when you click on "click here", the containing DIV moves up, when you click "close" the containing div is supposed to move back down to the original position. Problem is there is flicker when closing and the original position is set twice below reacting to a flicker when I press the "click here" button again.

```js
function domove() {
  document.getElementById('infograph').className = 'move-up object areaflaot ';
} //end of funciton 

function donomove() {
  document.getElementById('infograph').className = 'move-up object areaflaotdown ';
} //end of funciton
```

```css
.areaflaot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 278px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.move-up {
  transform: translate(0, -270px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -270px);
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -o-transform: translate(0, -270px);
  /** Opera **/
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -270px);
  /** Firefox **/
}

.object {
  posit ion: absolute;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  /** Firefox **/
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  /** Opera **/
}

.areaflaotdown {
  transform: translate(0, 270px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 270px);
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -o-transform: translate(0, 270px);
  /** Opera **/
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 270px);
  /** Firefox **/
}
```

```html
<div id="axis" class="one" style="width:200px;height:300px; background-color:#1F3234">
  <div class="object areaflaot " id="infograph" style="background-color:black;width:100px;height:100px;float:left; ">
    <div onclick="domove()" v style="color:white"> click here </div>
    <div onclick="donomove()" v style="color:white"> close </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: try using toggleClass() instead

Answer (score 0):

This is logic since you are removing/adding all the classes and especially the class that contains the transition. Instead you may consider adding/removing only the needed classes. Also the initial position is not `translate(0, -270px)` but `translate(0, 0)`. It's not an **addition** like you think `(270 + -270 = 0)` but it's a **setting** so you set the final values.

```js
function domove() {
  document.getElementById('infograph').classList.add('move-up');
  document.getElementById('infograph').classList.remove('areaflaotdown');
} //end of funciton 

function donomove() {
  document.getElementById('infograph').classList.remove('move-up');
  document.getElementById('infograph').classList.add('areaflaotdown');
} //end of funciton
```

```css
.areaflaot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 278px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.move-up {
  transform: translate(0, -270px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -270px);
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -o-transform: translate(0, -270px);
  /** Opera **/
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -270px);
  /** Firefox **/
}

.object {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  /** Firefox **/
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  /** Opera **/
}

.areaflaotdown {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  /** Opera **/
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  /** Firefox **/
}
```

```html
<div id="axis" class="one" style="width:200px;height:300px; background-color:#1F3234">
  <div class="object areaflaot " id="infograph" style="background-color:black;width:100px;height:100px;float:left; ">
    <div onclick="domove()" style="color:white"> click here </div>
    <div onclick="donomove()" style="color:white"> close </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can also optimize your code like this:

```js
function domove() {
  document.getElementById('infograph').classList.add('move-up');
} 
function donomove() {
  document.getElementById('infograph').classList.remove('move-up');
}
```

```css
.areaflaot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 278px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.move-up {
  transform: translate(0, -270px);
}

.object {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="axis" class="one" style="width:200px;height:300px; background-color:#1F3234">
  <div class="object areaflaot " id="infograph" style="background-color:black;width:100px;height:100px;float:left; ">
    <div onclick="domove()"  style="color:white"> click here </div>
    <div onclick="donomove()"  style="color:white"> close </div>
  </div>

</div>
```